# How do I create a probability distribution for the number of games people play in this scenario?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

From a population of individuals the following statistics are reported:

- 20% play league of legends (event L)
- 45% play dota (event D)
- 30% play halo (event H)
- 15% play league of legends and dota
- 20% play dota and halo
- 10% play league of legends and halo
- 5%  play all games mentioned.

Consider a randomly selected gamer from this population. Let Y= the number of games they play. Find a probability distribution for Y.

I don't see how I'd find any p values here. I'm not told how to find when Y=1, 2 or 3 since they're all combined? I was thinking I could do $P(Y\geq 1)$ , $P(Y\geq 2)$, $P(Y=3)$ but I'm not sure if that would answer the question.

Comment: You are given P(Y=3), P(Y>=2), and P(Y>=1), so subtract the intersections and you are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from $P(L\cap D\cap H)=\color{red}{0.05}$ and you must get the Venn diagram:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: ![![enter image description here]

Hence:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
Y&P(Y)\\
\hline
0&\color{green}{0.45}\\
1&\color{brown}{0.20}\\
2&\color{blue}{0.30}\\
3&\color{red}{0.05}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Make a Venn diagram and enter a percentage for each region.  The $5\%$ who play all three are counted among those who play each pair of games, so you can subtract that to get $15\%$ who play dota and halo but not legends.  Keep going.

Comment: +1. Lucky you. I was drawing and doing all the calculations. :)